# What is a safe and efficient temperature range for absorption chiller generators?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, fluid-dynamics, condensed-matter, pressure

I've read that the role generators play in the absorption chiller cycle is to concentrate the salt solution so that the evaporator/absorber can maintain a vacuum by constant absorption of vapour entering from the evaporator. Now considering the vacuum conditions, water could boil at 3 Celsius, which can easily serve our purpose of concentrating the salt solution.

Why then, do we have to use temperatures of around 80 Celsius? How does a higher generator temperature affect the cycle, provided all other factors remain constant? And why does too high a generator temperature become dangerous/inefficient?

Also, if possible, explain the relationship between the gas and liquid phases of water at the generator and condenser, because I believe that the more you evaporate water off, the higher the head pressure becomes, and thus raises the boiling point as the salt solution becomes concentrated.

I love diagrams. So if one of you could provide one to visually explain the concept, I'd be grateful.

Comment: This sounds more like an [engineering.se] question to me. You might have better luck finding someone familiar with the design of absorption refrigerators over there.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Thanks for nothing bro.

Comment: No problem, it's all I could give. All I know about absorption refrigerators is what's written in the first paragraph on Wikipedia, and only because I googled it it to try to figure out what you were talking about.